# Equation of the boundary between two classes

Tags: machine-learning, bayesian, classification, discriminant-analysis

I have a question about one task:
I have two classes w1 and w2 and we are working with 2D space. The density of each of the two classes are the folowing:
\begin{equation}
p(x = {(x_{1}, x_{2})}'| w_{1}) = \frac{1}{4}\cdot e ^{-\frac{x_{1}+ x_{2}}{2}}
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
p(x = {(x_{1}, x_{2})}'| w_{2}) = \frac{1}{16}\cdot x_{1}x_{2} \cdot e ^{-\frac{x_{1}+ x_{2}}{2}}
\end{equation}
How to find the equation of the boundary between the two classes.

Comment: For finding a Bayes decision boundary, you need the priors of these classes. Are they equally likely?

Comment: Yes, I think they are equally likely.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If they're equally likely, you'll just solve $p(x|w_1)=p(x|w_2)$ to find the decision boundary, which yields the curve $x_1x_2=4$.

Comment: Thanks, but if they are not equal we have **p(x|w1)p(w1) = p(x|w2)p(w2)** which I can't solved?

Comment: you can still solve it when you substitute the values.

Comment: How? Could you give some hint?

Comment: $$x_1x_2=4p(w_1)/p(w_2)$$

Comment: And this is not the equation, I guess? We must find a way to find the **p(w1)** and **p(w2)** ?

Comment: you can't find the priors, you need to know them. If they're equally likely, they're $0.5$, but if not, who knows what they're?